# lastindexof() and HEX 0x1A

Tags: java, hex

I'm new in *Java* and I want to find a single special character in a long string, using f.i. `lastIndexOf` or `indexOf`, just to know about the existance.

The character is hex `0x1A`. How can I use hex in `lastIndexOf` or `indexOf`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

```
text.indexOf('\u001A');
```

or

```
text.lastIndexOf((char) 0x1A);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

existence can be tested by the return value of these functions.

if it returns -1 then the given string /char is not present in the source string.